# Пусти козла в огород

Tags: перевод

How would you translate this to English?

Comment: It fits better in English stackexchange.

Comment: @Volodya No, it does not fit EL&U.SE at all. It would be deleted there immediately.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov I respectfully think that you're incorrect when it comes to EL&U, look at this for example: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102420/equivalent-of-sarcastic-song-non-ti-preoccupare-limportante-%C3%A8-partecipare-am

Comment: @Volodya I meant the present question in the present state – just a Russian phrase and request for translation. Of course you can ask for English idiom at EL&U.SE but you should provide explanation detailed enough to explain what do you want to person who cannot read in Russian. Actually, original phrase itself is not essential to get an answer (e. g. [Equivalent for the Russian idiom “to write into the drawer”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174059/equivalent-for-the-russian-idiom-to-write-into-the-drawer)).

Comment: @Volodya So Stack Exchange is not at place for asking help to translate something to English at all (at least until ‘English for Russian Speakers SE’ is created). You would better send questioners to [forum.lingvo.ru](http://forum.lingvo.ru) or similar places dedicated to _translations_.

Answer (score 3):

The actual expression is "Пусти́ козла́ в огоро́д, он всю капу́сту обдерёт" (Let a he-goat into the garden, and it will eat all the cabbage") and its English equivalent is "Never trust a wolf with the care of lambs".